# Red for +ve, black for 0v, ...which colour for -ve rail?

Tags: wiring, standard, colour-coding

I'm bodging together a bench PSU from an old server PSU, about to order a mixed bag of terminal posts for the front panel but then tripped over the problem that I'm not sure what's the correct or most common colour to use for the -ve rail on a split-rail supply.

Obviously there's red for +ve, black for 0v, green for earth... but what for the -ve rail?

Commonly available terminal colours are yellow and blue, and I'm aware that blue is used in -48v telecomms supplies (either as 0v *or* -48v depending which side of the EU standard you are, *headdesk*), so it's the front runner at the moment... unless you guys know different?

I thought I'd check here before I make a hideous faux-pas.

Comment: Red and black for positive and ground are common, but certainly not a universal standard for something like benchtop use.  Any color for a negative supply will be even less standard.  Use what you have around, although it would be good to keep away from red, black, and green.

Comment: Id have gone red, white and blue with white an indistinct and colorless 0v. Hang what other folk do. LOL

Comment: Black is colorless too.

Comment: I guess I brought this upon myself, ask a pedantic question, get pedantic comments... :D

Comment: No standard **BUT** | NOT yellow -  to be seen as highest V+. | NOT Orange = ambiguous. | Blue is a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would use a "cold" color for the negative such as blue or maybe purple.

[image]

One "standard" I can think of that's not incompatible with red=positive and black=0V is the standard [PC power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX) color code:

[image]
 For more info on wiring colour codes see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_code).

Comment: Yes, there is no real *standard*, but blue seems logical.

Comment: @felixphew Or, rather, there are many standards, many of them mutually incompatible (such as the DC power standards http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_5/chpt_2/2.html)

Comment: Or more succinctly: http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: +1 - I'd have suggested blue, as not being green or black, which may be more easily mistaken.

Comment: Purple (violet) is the standard color for negative supply, as far as I was taught.